# Live streaming webcam on a web page (most efficient solution)

Tags: flash, video-streaming, webcam

For a quick project I'll be working on, I have to install a multi-webcam setup that will be **live streamed** and accessible **via a web browser**.

I'm looking into the quickest and most efficient solution, the less time and hassle it takes to implement, the better. That means **buying hardware and/or software is not that much of an issue** (as long as it's not 1000$+ flash server software).

The requirements / basic setup:

- The web server will be directly connected the cams (via ethernet / WiFi).
- The stream should be viewable by the max possible audience so no ActiveX / VLC-style object embedding. **Flash would be ideal** (even if it's a paid solution).
- Bandwidth is not an issue, max 2-3 clients at a time, most of the time only one.

Any options could be considered, quick-n-dirty hacks included (eg. reloading a .jpeg image 20 times a second via AJAX).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did you look into the side of solution like this:

VLC server stream from webcams to -> Red 5 Server which streams over RTMP to -> flash clients.
If bandwidth and clients number is okay for traffic limitation - then its a good solution.

In  other cases it depends of quality you want end-user have:
you can even call webcams as IP cams and post them to simple LAMP server, and flash client will just grub that IP cams JPEGs and update them in some time interval.

So, let us know.
p.s. are you looking for some video solution for security reasons? :)
Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, I was indeed looking for insights on how a full live streaming stack might look like.

So, as I understand it (question marks where I don't quite understand what's happening):

1. VLC grabs the output of the cams and streams it over (?) to Red5

2. Red5 grabs the stream and converts (?) it to an RTMP stream

3. Flash player setup with the RTMP stream's address (?). This means I could grab some free Flash video player and have it play the stream quite easily.

Comment: And no, this is not for security purposes, but there will eventually be a security company that will have webcams setup for surveillance, would it be easier to get them to supply a video stream ? I'm thinking that because this is not something they might be used to, and because of security constraints, it wouldn't be very practical to get them involved.

Comment: 1) if you need good solution its always a good practice to hire some experts for good result.

Comment: 2) in answer to your  <?> - all of them streams via RTMP, the VLC just allow to convert mostly any webcam stream to RealTineMessagingProtocol Format, so we could stream it as video to clients(MANY clients) and this many client will allow Red5(as hub).

Comment: Ok, I think I have a rough understanding of each of the tool's roles, but what does it amount to in practice ? Would this kind of setup take a long time to put together, in a reliable, hassle-free way ? Again, my main concern is this has to take as little time to put in place as possible.

Comment: BTW, your IP cam + Flash video player with JPEGs solution looks promising, what framerate do you suspect I could achieve with such a setup? Also, aren't there any IP cams that provide a ready to use stream that could be fed to a "standard" Flash video player ?

Comment: framerate will depends of web cams quality + web server inet speed of connection + number of users. Also make clear what kind of proejct is this? If its open source or home-like then I think you have some time to study little manuals and it will take around a week to setup all solution from zero on your servers. If its business project, I should start from budget line to determine what the end-solution will cost. Thank you :)

Comment: This would be a few cams on a web page live streamed, but not many concurrent clients. It's a "business" project, in the sense that it has a budget, but still, the most efficient the better. Thanks for your answers !